# How can I find camera pose from matlab calibration?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

As far as I know the Caltech Matlab toolbox gives the internal camera parameters (focal length, principle point,...) and camera matrix.

As external camera parameters it gives the transformation matrices for each image used in the calibration (chessboard pattern).

My question is how can I find the pose of the camera given the internal and external parameters from Caltech matlab calibration toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Pose relative to what?  The extrinsic parameters give you the pose of the camera relative to the checkerboard in each of the calibration images. Pose here is represented as a translation and a rotation from the checkerboard's coordinate system into the camera's coordinate system.

By the way, there is now [support for camera calibration in the Computer Vision System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/camera-calibration-with-matlab-81233.html). There is also a function called `extrinsics`, which computes the pose of a calibrated camera (in terms of translation and rotation) relative to a world coordinate system (e. g. represented by checkerboard points).

Comment: Hallo Dima, I need the pose relative to the ground plan, i.e. the tilt, roll and pan angles and the elevation of the camera (height of the camera above ground plan)